# jQuery datepicker not setting the maxDate in textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery.ui.datepicker in my code. I have set `maxDate` to `+0` i.e. current date. So in the calendar control the future dates are disabled but user is still able to key in the future date in the textbox. How to restrict the user to enter only the dates less than maxDate and if user enter any future date I want to show the current date in the textbox on blur.

```
$txtDate.datepicker({
    dateFormat: MyPage.config.dateFormat,
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        try {
            $.datepicker.parseDate(MyPage.config.dateFormat, dateText);
        } catch (e) {
            $txtDate.val('');
        };
    },
    maxDate: '+0'
});
$txtDate.datepicker('setDate', new Date()).blur(function () {
    try {
        if ($txtDate.val() == '') {
            $txtDate.datepicker('setDate', new Date());
        }
    }
    catch (ex) {
        var MyEx = MyWeb.Exception(ex);
        MyEx.AddData("Method", "$txtDate.datepicker('setDate', new Date()).blur");
        $.errorhandler("HandleError", MyEx);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your input html element:

```
readonly="readonly"
```

And use a serverside technology to default the value to today's date:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>">
```

Comment: ..but that will restrict the user to enter the past dates. I want user to either select the date from picker or type manually (date less than maxDate).

Comment: ohh, i'm sorry then, i misunderstood your question, i've used the datepicker a bunch, and i always prevent actually typing in text, i think people prefer using the datepicker anyway, but it's your choice ....